# <input type="range" /> not working on iOS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html5, aura, salesforce1-app

I've created a very basic lightning component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" />
</aura:component>
```

This appears to be working perfectly:

- In Firefox, Chrome and Safari (on both mobile and PC) via `/one/one.app` as well as `/namespace/sf1app.app`

Working on touch, but not drag-and-slide:

- Inside the SF1 app on Android

**Not working at all:**

- **Inside the SF1 app on iOS**

> [This documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lightning_components/lightning_components_uiforce) says that there is a `ui:inputRange`
>   component, but when I try to add it in a component I get the following
>   error:
>
> > Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named inputRange found: Source
>
> Then I referred to the aura documentation at
>   `https://<INSTANCE>.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app` which
>   doesn't have `inputRange` listed.
>
> **UPDATE:**  [I found the answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81568/error-saving-lighting-component-uiblock)

**Question(s):**

Has anyone created a slider in a lightning component that works on iOS too? Is it a SF1 app limitation that doesn't support all HTML5 components?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [source](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/2a73dfbf835204d8d0b85dc0b78dd249fd8d8486/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputRange/inputRange.cmp) for `ui:inputRange` in the Aura open source [project](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura).

This is a feature that exists in the open source framework, but does not appear to be surfaced on the platform implementation of aura that is Lightning Component Framework (LCF).

The Winter 16 [release](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_components_ga.htm?edition=&impact=) saw Lightning Components go GA. If you look at the `ui:inputText` [component](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/2a73dfbf835204d8d0b85dc0b78dd249fd8d8486/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputText/inputText.cmp), you can see that this has an attribute set as `access="global"` this is the flag for what has been implemented in the platform and been made available to Salesforce developers to build with.

During the developer preview and beta over the past year there were a number of components that had been surfaced in the LCF project. For GA, a few of these were removed. I suspect that `ui:inputRange` was one of these.

More and more should be surfaced in the future. I would suggest Idea Exchange to begin raising the profile of some of the components that you'd like to see move from open source to LCF. You can also browse the project for what is availble by accessing the open source [docs](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference), or browsing the components [source](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/2a73dfbf835204d8d0b85dc0b78dd249fd8d8486/aura-components/src/main/components).

Comment: This is very confusing to me. `<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" />`is not working on any iOS device in the context of one/one.app. It works in Safari or Chrome on iOs when visiting a website like: http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php
Whats more, if I post the html5tutorial link in chatter and open within Sf1 the slider works somewhat (not perfect but at least I can move it)
I also tried CConraets Dreamhouse App http://www.dreamhouseapp.io/ without any luck. No slider working there either. 
Any wisdom greatly appreciated