# Simple input field not working in Salesforce1 mobile app in iOS 8

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, ios

I have a *very* simple input field in a visualforce page being displayed in the native Salesforce1 app for iOS. When I enter some text and then scroll, the keyboard stops working:

http://gyazo.com/253d47cba43c6eab32105e7f04129c95

However, this same page works when I access the app through Safari:

https://gyazo.com/37627faaa6a334f1ea721f3af63d4fe6

I'm using the latest version of the Salesforce1 iOS app, running iOS 8.3.

Here's the code:

```
<apex:page doctype="html-5.0">
    <div>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

The code is so basic, I have no idea why it's not working in the Salesforce1 iOS app...any ideas?

Comment: I have similar problem http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81562/input-type-range-not-working-on-ios . It'd be good to get a proper answer from someone at Salesforce working on this product.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this problem last year, and had a long round of interactions with Salesforce Support about it. In the end, this has come down to being a bug on Apple's side, which they are tracking. You should be able to see most of the relevant information here:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5l1AAC

There are a couple of possible workarounds listed there, but for our product, we ended up just having to live with the bug for now. :/